# C++- (If statements) Else always gets displayed

Tags: c++, inheritance, if-statement

So I have this base class of mine.

```
class Info{
private:
    string name, sex;
    int year, month, day, age;

public:

    void setInfo(){

    string n, s;

        cout<<"Enter your full name: ";
        cin>>n;
        cout<<"Gender: ";
        cin>>s;

        name=n;
        sex=s;

        cout<<endl;
    }

    void setBirthdate(){

        int y, m, d, a;

        cout<<"Birthdate in numerical type"<<endl;
        cout<<"Year: ";
        cin>>y;
        cout<<"Month: ";
        cin>>m;
        cout<<"Day: ";
        cin>>d;

        a=2014-y;

        year=y;
        month=m;
        day=d;
        age=a;

        cout<<endl;
    }

    int getYear(){
        return year;        
    }

    int getMon(){
        return month;
    }

    int getDay(){
        return day;
    }

    int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

};
```

And a Derived class

```
class Fortunes:public Info{

private:
    string zodiacs;

public:

Info fo1;

    string getZodiac(){

        if((fo1.getMon()<=4) && (fo1.getMon()>=3))
        {
        cout<<"Aries";
        }

        else
            cout<<"aww";

    }




};
```

main class

```
int main(){
Fortunes f;

f.setInfo();
f.setBirthdate();
f.getZodiac();

cout<<endl;

system("pause>nul");
}
```

I wanted to make a program that tells your zodiac sign base from the info you entered.
So I just tested this small code of mine the else always gets displayed.
I guessing that my operators are wrong? please help me :(

Comment: the if-statements in my derived class.The else always gets displayed.

Comment: Without knowing your test values, we can't tell. But this looks odd:  `if((fo1.getMon()<=4) && (fo1.getMon()>=3))` since it's only true for month 3 or month 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two instances of Info object created, one as sub-object of f(declared as Fortunes f;) and other declared as Info fo1; within Fortune object but fo1 is not initialized. Corrected program follows:

```
    class Fortunes:public Info{
    public:
        string getZodiac(){

            if((this->getMon()<=4) && (this->getMon()>=3))
            {
            cout<<"Aries";
            }

            else
                cout<<"aww";

        }

};
```

Comment: @polarysekt so many thanks, it was a typos

Comment: hehe, I deleted that comment upon your edit. always easier to detect on 'someone else's answer'. (if only i could detect things like that in my own code...).

Comment: Don't know "this", my professor didn't teach us "this"
It helped Thanks so I'm going to use "this" on every zodiac I will use.
btw is their any alternative way instead of using this?

Comment: this means pointer to current object, even if you dopn't use this, it's implied

Comment: @AhriOmg You could save quite a few function calls by either storing the result of `this->getMon()` in a variable and using the variable in the if statements or using a `switch` statement.